# How to change element name in C# REST service post call

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I have a a REST interface method:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class SEPTABLINE
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string LGNUM;
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string LABOR;
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string MATNR;
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string ACTIVE;
    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string MAX_DAYS;
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SEPTAB", Method = "POST")]
Stream AddSEPTAB(List<SEPTABLINE> separationTabLines);
```

To call this method I have to use the following structure:

```
<ArrayOfSEPTABLINE>
  <SEPTABLINE>
    <LGNUM>String content</LGNUM>
    <LABOR>String content</LABOR>
    <MATNR>String content</MATNR>
    <ACTIVE>String content</ACTIVE>
    <MAX_DAYS>String content</MAX_DAYS>
  </SEPTABLINE>
  <SEPTABLINE>
    <LGNUM>String content</LGNUM>
    <LABOR>String content</LABOR>
    <MATNR>String content</MATNR>
    <ACTIVE>String content</ACTIVE>
    <MAX_DAYS>String content</MAX_DAYS>
  </SEPTABLINE>
</ArrayOfSEPTABLINE>
```

How can I change the name ArrayOfSEPTABLINE to SEPTAB?
Or is it possible to change the call to

```
  <SEPTABLINE>
    <LGNUM>String content</LGNUM>
    <LABOR>String content</LABOR>
    <MATNR>String content</MATNR>
    <ACTIVE>String content</ACTIVE>
    <MAX_DAYS>String content</MAX_DAYS>
  </SEPTABLINE>
  <SEPTABLINE>
    <LGNUM>String content</LGNUM>
    <LABOR>String content</LABOR>
    <MATNR>String content</MATNR>
    <ACTIVE>String content</ACTIVE>
    <MAX_DAYS>String content</MAX_DAYS>
  </SEPTABLINE>
```

without the ArrayOfSEPTABLINE?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you should try this

```
public class StreamList
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Stream> Stream;
}

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SEPTAB", Method = "POST")]
StreamList AddSEPTAB(List<SEPTABLINE> separationTabLines);
```